# Yii2 MySQL table names and HTTP404 errors

Tags: mysql, yii2, http-status-code-404

I am new to the Yii technology, but having worked in IT for many years I hoped I understood generally how software is designed. But the Yii guys have got me good.

I have been trying to understand why I am getting HTTP404 errors.

I have a Win 10 environment using MySQL, with latest versions of MySQL and PHP. I naively assumed that Yii would support the nomenclature standards for objects in the MySQL, especially table names. However it appears I am wrong, so here is a heads up for those interested.

I use all lower case characters for my table names, and where I have a table that is a link between two entities I use a name such as entity1_entity2. I use gii to generate a model from this table and the the CRUD option to generate a basic initial application.

I have the pretty URL active, so the initial URL I use is :
\localhost\Movies\movieactor

Where Movies is the website name defined to IIS (virtual directory) and movieactor is the lowercase name I used for the model and controller objects. The actual name prefix I used was MovieActor for the model and controller objects. I used movieactor for the view sub-directory.

Much to my surprise I was presented with an HTTP404 error message. I spent most of a day trying to understand what I had done wrong.

After a good sleep, I started again the next morning. I decided to try changing the name of the relevant table from movie_actor to movieactor. I then regenerated the model, and CRUD components. This time when I invoked the same URL I was pleasantly surprised to see the web application show me the data.

I have no idea what restrictions the Yii guys place on table names, no documentation that I can find, but this is my experience, and hopefully it may save others some grief.

Have I missed something or is my story correct ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in Yii there are no requirements for table names. Table or model class names are not directly related to URLs.

When you are using gii to generate model you are prompted to enter the table name. Then the model name is suggested as pascal case version of table name. For example if your table is named `movie_actor` the suggested model class name will be `MovieActor`. But you don't have to accept that, you can change it to whatever you want.

Then when you are generating CRUD it asks you to enter model class, search model class and controller class. The model class here is the `MovieActor` generated earlier. Search model class can be whatever you like, but what is important for URL is the controller class. There is something called **controller id** based on controller class name. It's a kebab case version of controller class name after removing the `Controller` suffix. If you name your controller as `MovieActorController` its controller id will be `movie-actor`. It's this **controller id** that you need to use in your url to reach that controller. So, url you have to use for this controller would be `\localhost\Movies\movie-actor`. You need to use same controller id as a sub-directory for your views too.

When you've decided to change table name to `movieactor` you've probably also generated the controller as `MovieactorController`. Because of that its id was `movieactor` and your url and views subfolder were correct.